# RailwaysのEnter URL partはどうやったら出現するのでしょうか？

Tags: rubymine

[JetBrains Plugin Repository :: Railways](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7110?pr=)
に
[screenshot_14915.png (650×292)](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/files/7110/screenshot_14915.png)
が記載されていますが、これはどうやったら出現するのでしょうか、

とりあえずCtr + Shift + gを試してみましたが出現せず、
command + shift + gでも出ませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cmd+Shfit+Gが他のアクションに奪われているせいだと思います。
Preferences > Keymap で現在のキーマップを確認してください。

以下の図の赤丸を使うと、実際にショートカットを入力して該当するアクションを検索することができます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ショートカットが重複して定義されているなら、どちらかのアクションにコンフリクトしない新しいキーマップをアサインすればOKです。
対象のアクションを右クリックして、Add Keyboard Shortcutを選択してください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ここでも実際にショートカットを入力して、ショートカットを定義することができます。
また、新しいショートカットもコンフリクトしている場合はウインドウ内にその旨が警告されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Rilways自体は、command + shift + gであることが確認でき、他とかぶっていたので、空いているものを割り振ることができました。